# macOS 12.4 - launchd service unable to access files in users directory

Tags: macos, go, launchd

After upgrading to macOS 12.4 our Golang app which runs as a service on macOS is unable to read files in the user's home directory. Even when the file is readable for all the users. The service runs as root and we still get the following error:

```
if error := viper.ReadInConfig(); error != nil {
   // error: open /Users/adnan/Downloads/test371/config.yml: operation not permitted
}
```

If I try running the app as `sudo ./myserverapp` it works fine and is able to read the file but fails when run as a service.

Answer (score 1):

It worked after giving "Full Disk Access" to the binary. Is there any alternative for this? Asking each of our customers to do that seems problematic.